# Sufficient/complete statistic $\leftrightarrow$ injective/surjective map?

Tags: sufficient-statistics, function, complete-statistics

I can't understand the paragraph in [Completeness (statistics) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Completeness_(statistics)&oldid=1164982729):

> We have an identifiable model space parameterised by $\theta$, and a statistic $T$. Then consider the map $f:p_{\theta }\mapsto p_{T|\theta }$ which takes each distribution on model parameter $\theta$ to its induced distribution on statistic $T$. The statistic $T$ is said to be complete when $f$ is surjective, and sufficient when $f$ is injective.
>
> ([added on 2023-07-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Completeness_(statistics)&diff=prev&oldid=1164982729) without any citation, and there's no revision after that)

- **What does “*distribution on $\theta$*” mean?**

  Domain of $f$ is all  prior distribution of $\theta$ (in Bayesian sense), or the famliy of distributions of samples ($X_1, \ldots, X_n$)?
- **What is the codomain of $f$?**

  I guess the image of $f$ is all possible distribution of $T$ (i.e. the famliy of distributions of $T$), but codomain should be larger than that, or $f$ is always surjective.

### My thoughts

Sufficiency and completeness are related but independent concepts, as discussed in the following questions. If the statement in Wikipedia is true, then it’s a clear explanation of sufficiency and completeness.

- [exponential family - Are complete statistics always sufficient? - Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187869/are-complete-statistics-always-sufficient)
- [Is a minimal sufficient statistic also a complete statistic - Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272531/is-a-minimal-sufficient-statistic-also-a-complete-statistic)

Roughly speaking:

- $T$ is **sufficient**: $T$ provides all information of $\theta$ from $X$, and we can recover the *whole* distribution of $X$ once given $T$.

  $f$ is **injective**: If we know that $y$ is $f$ of some $x$, then there is *exactly* one $x$ that satisfies $y = f(x)$.
- $T$ is **complete**: For any function $g$, whenever $\operatorname{\mathbb{E}} g(T) \equiv 0$, then $\Pr(g(T) = 0) \equiv 1$, where “$\equiv$” means $\forall \theta$.

  $f$ is **surjective**: For any two functions $g, g'$, whenever $g \circ f = g \circ f$, then $g = g'$.

I can *feel* that these concepts are connected, but I can’t make it rigorous…

### Alternative comprehension of sufficiency and completeness

[Basic intuition about minimal sufficient statistic - Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166661/basic-intuition-about-minimal-sufficient-statistic?rq=1): $T$ can be seen as an indexed partition of the sample space.

[st.statistics - Is a function of complete statistics again complete? - MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/182661): $\operatorname{\mathbb{E}} g(T) \equiv 0$ means the distributions of $T$ for varying $\theta$ span the whole space of functions of $T$.

Comment: I'll accept my own answer because there's no other answer…

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196601/what-is-the-intuition-behind-defining-completeness-in-a-statistic-as-being-impos/197432#197432

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen I've read all 2 answers there. They provide good intuition on how estimators work, but I can't see how they are related to the map $f$ here. Could you explain more specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to clarify the [statistical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model#Formal_definition) $(\Omega,\mathcal{P})$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space, and $\mathcal{P} = \{P_\theta: \theta \in \Theta \}$ is the set of probability distributions on $\Omega$, and $\Theta$ is the parameter space. Those $\Omega, P_\theta$ are those in the [probability triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P_\theta)$.

- $\Omega \overset{X}{\to} \mathcal{X} \overset{T}{\to} \mathcal{T}$, where $X$ is called a random variable, $T$ is called a statistic.
- $\mathcal{F} \overset{P_\theta}{\to} \mathbb{R}$.

We say that the model is [identifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability) if the mapping $\theta \mapsto P_\theta$ is injective.

> What does “*distribution on $\theta$*” mean?

The domain of $f$ is neither prior distributions, nor the family of distributions of $X$. It is $\mathcal{P}$.

> What is the codomain of $f$?

All $\mathcal{T} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions. This is different from and larger than the family of induced distributions of $T$, because the latter is $\{P_{T|\theta}: \theta \in \Theta\}$ where $P_{T|\theta}(t) = P_\theta(X^{-1}(T^{-1} (t)))$, and the former includes functions that cannot be represented by $P_\theta$.

#### $T$ is sufficient $\iff$ $f$ is injective

My rough thoughts are right here.

- $\implies$

  If $T$ is sufficient, then $P_{X|T,\Theta}(x, t;\theta)$ does not depends on $\theta$. That is to say, $\forall x \in \mathcal{X}, \forall t \in \mathcal{T}, \forall \theta_1, \theta_2 \in \Theta$, $P_{X|T,\Theta}(x,t;\theta_1) = P_{X|T,\Theta}(x,t;\theta_2)$.

  Now let’s prove $f$ is injective.

  For any $P_{T|\theta_1}$ and $P_{T|\theta_2}$ in the image of $f$, if $P_{T|\theta_1} = P_{T|\theta_2}$ (i.e. $\forall t \in \mathcal{T}, P_{T|\theta_1}(t) = P_{T|\theta_2}(t)$), then $\forall x \in \mathcal{X}, \forall t \in \mathcal{T}$,
  $$
    P_{\theta_1}(x)
    = P_{T|\theta_1}(t) \times P_{X|T,\Theta}(x,t;\theta_1)
    = P_{T|\theta_2}(t) \times P_{X|T,\Theta}(x,t;\theta_2)
    = P_{\theta_2}(x).
    $$
  This is exactly the definition of $P_{\theta_1} = P_{\theta_2}$.
- $\impliedby$

  Similarly, for any $P_{T|\theta_1}, P_{T|\theta_2}$ in the image of $f$, then $P_{\theta_1} = P_{\theta_2}$. By the definition of conditional distribution,
  $$
    P_{X|T,\Theta}(x,t;\theta)
    = \frac{P_{\theta}(X =x \land T(x) = t)}{P_{T|\theta}(t)}
    = \frac{P_{\theta}(x)}{P_{T|\theta}(t)}.
    $$
  Therefore $P_{X|T,\Theta}$ is same for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

#### $T$ is complete $\iff$ f is surjective

It looks like that this has nothing to do with cancelability. Instead it’s related to the geometric intuition:

> [st.statistics - Is a function of complete statistics again complete? - MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/182661): $\operatorname{\mathbb{E}} g(T) \equiv 0$ means the distributions of $T$ for varying $\theta$ span the whole space of functions of $T$.

1. $\operatorname{\mathbb{E}} g(T)$ is an inner product of $P_{T|\theta}$ and $g$.
2. $\operatorname{\mathbb{E}} g(T) \equiv 0$ means $g \perp \{P_{T|\theta}: \theta \in \Theta\}$.
3. Moreover, if the only perpendicular $g$ is $0$ (almost surely), then $\{P_{T|\theta}: \theta \in \Theta \}$ spans the whole $\mathcal{T} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions. This is the meaning of “$f$ is surjective”. (It’s not the normal meaning — we let them span here.)

#### Examples

##### Sufficient but not complete

$\Theta = \mathbb{R}$, $X \sim \mathcal{U}(\theta, \theta+2\pi)$ and $T = X$.

- $T$ is **sufficient**: $T$ gives the same information of $\theta$ as $X$.

  $f$ is **injective**: It’s the identity map!
- $T$ is not **complete**: $\operatorname{\mathbb{E}} \sin X \equiv 0$ no matter how $\sin X$ is distributed.

  $f$ is not **surjective**:

  - $\mathcal{T} = \mathbb{R}$ so codomain of $f$ is all functions on $\mathbb{R}$.
  - The image of $f$ is $\{\boldsymbol{1}_{[\theta, \theta+2\pi]}: \theta \in \mathbb{R} \}$, where $\boldsymbol{1}$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

    Its intersection to the set of $2\pi$-periodic functions is the set of constant functions. In other words, the image of $f$ cannot span functions with period $2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi$ and so on.

    Alternatively, the Fourier transform of $\boldsymbol{1}_{[\theta, \theta+2\pi]}$ is $2\pi \operatorname{sinc}(\pi \omega) e^{-i(\theta-\pi)\omega}$, which has zeros at $\omega = 1,2,\ldots$.

##### Constant statistic

- $T$ is not **sufficient**: Obvious.

  $f$ is not **injective**: $f$ always maps to the same singleton distribution.
- $T$ is **complete**: $g(T)$ is deterministic. It has to be $0$ if the expectation is $0$.

  $f$ is **surjective**: $\mathcal{T}$ is a one-point set, so any $\mathcal{T} \to \mathbb{R}$ function is a basis of codomain of $f$.

##### Ignore some samples

First we work out a complete and sufficient statistic for $n$ samples. Now we're given more samples but we stick to the old statistic.

- $T$ is not **sufficient**: Obvious.

  $f$ is not **injective**: $\Omega \overset{X}{\to} \mathcal{X} \overset{T}{\to} \mathcal{T}$, now $\Omega$ becomes $\Omega \times \Omega'$ and $\mathcal{X}$ becomes $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X'}$. The domain of $f$ expands but the codomain does not change.
- $T$ is **complete**: Completeness tells about the family of distributions of $T$, it’s not related to $X$. So $T$ is still complete even we receive more samples.

  $f$ is **surjective**: The codomain and the image of $f$ does not change.

Answer (score 1):

> A complete statistic T is one for which any proposed distribution on the domain of T is predicted by one or more prior distributions on the model parameter space.

I doubt whether that statement is true. Say we have as sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ with

$$X_i \sim N(\mu, 1)$$

then the sample mean is a sufficient and complete statistic and is distributed as

$$\bar{X}|\mu \sim N(\mu, 1/\sqrt{n})$$

The distribution of the sample mean conditional on a prior distribution for the parameter $\mu$ will be a convolution which is similar to Gaussian smoothening and the variance will be at least $1/\sqrt{n}$.

This means that not every distribution for $\bar{X}$ can be mapped backwards to a prior on $\mu$. And the mapping in the question is not surjective for this example. Yet, the statistic is a complete statistic.

---

On mathoverflow there's an explanation of completeness that get's close to it

https://mathoverflow.net/a/182661

> Geometrically, completeness means something like this: if a vector $g(T)$ is orthogonal to the p.d.f. $f_\theta$ of $T$ for each $\theta$,
> $$\mathbb E_\theta g(T) = \langle g(T),f_\theta\rangle=0$$
> then $g(T)=0$ i.e., the functions $f_\theta$ for varying $\theta$ span the whole space of functions of $T$.

So the space of linear combinations of pdf's $f_{\theta}(T)$ of the statiatic is complete (it contains any function $g(T)$). Any function $g(T)$ can be described as an integral

$$g(T) = \int h(\theta) f_{\theta}(T)\, \text{d}\theta$$

but here $h(\theta)$ is not a distribution on $\theta$; it doesn't need to integrate to 1, and it can have negative values.

Comment: I agree with you (see “$T$ is complete $\iff$ $f$ is surjective” in my answer), and I think the _surjective_ here should not be the normal meaning — we let them span here.

I am wondering if we restrict the codomain to all functions that integrates to $1$, then can $f$ be surjective in the normal sense?

Comment: I guess my hypothesis is still wrong. As you said, the variance will be at least $1/n$.